# AWS Cloudformation - Installing packages with cfn-init

Tags: bash, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have created an EC2 instance via cloudformation and I am trying to get it to install postgres on the instance directly via cloudformation. However, when I SSH into my instance and try to run `psql` via the command line I keep getting:

```
bash: psql: command not found
```

I have tried doing it manually, installing postgres with the below command and it works fine.

`sudo yum install postgresql postgresql-server postgresql-devel postgresql-contrib postgresql-docs`

Could it be that it is because I'm just updating the stack and thus the ec2 instance rather than creating a new one?

Below is a snippet from the cloudformation template. Everything works when I update the template but it seems that postgres still isn't installed...

```
  DbWrapper:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init: 
        config: 
          packages: 
            yum:
              postgresql: []
              postgresql-server: []
              postgresql-devel: []
              postgresql-contrib: []
              postgresql-docs: []
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-f976839e #AMI aws linux 2
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      AvailabilityZone: eu-west-2a
      SecurityGroupIds:
      - !Ref Ec2SecurityGroup
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetA
      KeyName: !Ref KeyPairName
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64:
          !Join [ "", [
            "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
            "sudo yum update\n",
            "sudo yum install -y aws-cfn-bootstrap\n", #download aws helper scripts
            "sudo /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ", #use cfn-init to install packages in cloudformation init
            !Sub "--stack ${AWS::StackName} ",
            "--resource DbWrapper ",
            "--configsets Install ",
            !Sub "--region ${AWS::Region} ",
            "\n" ] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is encountering the same problem, the solution was indeed that you need to delete the instance and recreate from scratch. Just updating the stack won't work.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late here (I found this searching for another issue), but you can re-run your CF Launch Config with this piece from your snippet:

```
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64:
          !Join [ "", [
            "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
            "sudo yum update\n",
            "sudo yum install -y aws-cfn-bootstrap\n", #download aws helper scripts
            "sudo /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ", #use cfn-init to install packages in cloudformation init
            !Sub "--stack ${AWS::StackName} ",
            "--resource DbWrapper ",
            "--configsets Install ",
            !Sub "--region ${AWS::Region} ",
            "\n" ] ]
```

the `/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init` command is what's running the metadata config from the launch config you've specified, which is where your packages are defined.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-init.html

The reason deleting the instance and recreating it works is that it re-runs the `UserData` piece from the EC2 section above.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to you calling `cfn-init` with `--configsets` value that you do not have defined. You would need to add the **configSets** section below to  your metadata section:

```
Metadata:
  AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
    configSets:
      Install:
        - "config"
    config: 
      packages: 
        yum:
          postgresql: []
          postgresql-server: []
          postgresql-devel: []
          postgresql-contrib: []
          postgresql-docs: []
```

Otherwise take out `--configset` from your `cfn-init` original call.

References:

[cfn-init](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-init.html)

[AWS::CloudFormation::Init](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html)